# Create a data frame with decimal values

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a data frame containing 2 columns with values from -2 to 10. The issue here is that I need the number of rows to be equal to the number of rows of another data frame (usually > 60 rows) in the environment. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of values? Random values from -2 to 10?

Comment: @M.Viking ascending values (From -2 to 10). Anyway, bird's solution answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `seq` is what you are looking for? For example:

```
seq(-2, 10, length.out = 60)
```

```
[1] -2.00000000 -1.79661017 -1.59322034 -1.38983051 -1.18644068 -0.98305085 -0.77966102 -0.57627119 -0.37288136 -0.16949153  0.03389831  0.23728814
[13]  0.44067797  0.64406780  0.84745763  1.05084746  1.25423729  1.45762712  1.66101695  1.86440678  2.06779661  2.27118644  2.47457627  2.67796610
[25]  2.88135593  3.08474576  3.28813559  3.49152542  3.69491525  3.89830508  4.10169492  4.30508475  4.50847458  4.71186441  4.91525424  5.11864407
[37]  5.32203390  5.52542373  5.72881356  5.93220339  6.13559322  6.33898305  6.54237288  6.74576271  6.94915254  7.15254237  7.35593220  7.55932203
[49]  7.76271186  7.96610169  8.16949153  8.37288136  8.57627119  8.77966102  8.98305085  9.18644068  9.38983051  9.59322034  9.79661017 10.00000000
```

If so, you can create a `dataframe` like so:

```
df = data.frame(column1 = seq(-2, 10, length.out = 60),
                column2 = seq(-2, 10, length.out = 60))
nrow(df)
[1] 60
```

```
head(df)

     column1    column2
1 -2.0000000 -2.0000000
2 -1.7966102 -1.7966102
3 -1.5932203 -1.5932203
4 -1.3898305 -1.3898305
5 -1.1864407 -1.1864407
6 -0.9830508 -0.9830508
```

Comment: Yes, it is. I just switched the lenght.out to along.with, to take the same length from the other data frame mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This makes a data.frame with two columns (x and y), each with the number of rows matching the iris dataset, random-uniform (`runif()`) distribution values from -2 to 10.

```
data.frame(x= runif(nrow(iris), min = -2, max = 10),
           y= runif(nrow(iris), min = -2, max = 10))
```

output

> ```
>             x         y
> 1 -1.43512771 -1.146855
> 2  0.49621051  6.412353
> 3  5.97574288  2.930192
> 4 -1.23759456  1.131674
> 5 -0.03594651  1.788106
> 6 -0.05291078  4.411346
> ...
> ```